# glossaries package reference non-glossary item in see also

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries

I'd like to be able to reference a section, table or other `\label`ed item when defining an acronym or other glossary entry. The `glossaries` package uses the `see` attribute or `\glssee` command to set up cross-referencing, but cross-referencing does not seem to support non-glossary items, such as sections, tables, figures, etc.

I've tried just typing into the `description` something like `see \autoref{whatever}`, but this doesn't look the same as other glossary entries. My hack is particularly painful for acronyms, as shown below, because you need to manually enter `first` and `short`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopostdot,section,numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\makeglossaries

% the way i'd like it to work...
  \newacronym{ACR}{ACR}{horrible spelling of acronym}
  \glssee[see]{ACR}{sect:acr}

% a way that almost works...
% but it is not consistent the the see= attribute (one is before one is after)
  \newglossaryentry{ACR2}{
    type=\acronymtype,
    name={ACR2},
    description={horrendous spelling of acronym, \emph{see \autoref{sect:acr}}},
    first={horrendous spelling of acronym (ACR2)},
    short={ACR2}
  }

% linking to another glossary entry
  \newglossaryentry{nice-ref}{
    name={nice ref},
    description={nice ref cleanly uses the \texttt{glossaries}
                 packages built-in see attribute to point to ACR.},
    see={another-entry}
  }
  \newglossaryentry{another-entry}{
    name={another entry},
    description={another entry}
  }


\begin{document}

\section{First section}
I'm using \gls{ACR} and \gls{ACR2}.

Now onto interesting things, like \gls{another-entry} and \gls{nice-ref}.

\section{Second section, this one about ACR}
\label{sect:acr}

  \gls{ACR} and \gls{ACR2} are awesome\ldots soooooooo awesome.

  \printglossary

\end{document}
```

Example output:
[image: Example of different behaviors and inability to reference non-glossary items]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally the `glossaries` package uses the `makeindex`/`xindy` cross-referencing mechanism. The `see` key and `\glssee` command are provided as a safeguard against misspelling the referenced term or cross-referencing a non-existent term, but you don't have to use them. They also provide a processor-independent interface, since `makeindex` and `xindy` have different ways of tagging cross-references. With `makeindex`, this is just done by using a formatting command that takes two arguments: the first is the cross-referenced text and the second is the location, which is ignored.

So you can just define a command that takes your label as the argument:

```
\newcommand*{\seeref}[2]{\emph{see} \autoref{#1}}
```

and reference the entry using that command as the format:

```
\newacronym{ACR2}{ACR2}{horrible spelling of acronym}
\glsadd[format=seeref{sect:acr}]{ACR2}
```

Here's the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopostdot,section,numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ACR}{ACR}{horrible spelling of acronym}

\newcommand*{\seeref}[2]{\emph{see} \autoref{#1}}

\newacronym{ACR2}{ACR2}{horrible spelling of acronym}
\glsadd[format=seeref{sect:acr}]{ACR2}

% linking to another glossary entry
  \newglossaryentry{nice-ref}{
    name={nice ref},
    description={nice ref cleanly uses the \texttt{glossaries}
                 packages built-in see attribute to point to ACR.},
    see={another-entry}
  }
  \newglossaryentry{another-entry}{
    name={another entry},
    description={another entry}
  }

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
I'm using \gls{ACR} and \gls{ACR2}.

Now onto interesting things, like \gls{another-entry} and \gls{nice-ref}.

\section{Second section, this one about ACR}
\label{sect:acr}

  \gls{ACR} and \gls{ACR2} are awesome\ldots soooooooo awesome.

  \printglossary

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]