# Linking appendices inside glossary with glossaries package

Tags: glossaries

I can easily link an acronym to a glossary term as folows:

```
\newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{ip}}]{IP}{IP}{Inntellectual Property\glsadd{ip}}
\newglossaryentry{ip}{%
    name={IP},%
    description={A reusable unit of logic, cell, or integrated circuit layout design that is the intellectual property of one party},%
}
```

How could I link a glossary term to an appendix? Something like that:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{finfet}{%
    name={FinFET},%
    description={A MOSFET transistor built on a substrate where the gate is placed on two, three, or four sides of the channel or wrapped around the channel, forming a double gate structure.},%
    see={Appendix \ref{sec:finfet-transistors}}
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First chapter}
    After \glspl{finfet} were introduced, leakage power of ASIC...
    \appendix
    \chapter{FinFET Transistors}
    \label{sec:finfet-transistors}
    \printglossary
\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output 
[image]
And results in an error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.6 ...fet-transistors' on page 1 undefined}}{Z}}}
                                                  %
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

Comment: The value of the `see` key may only be a comma-separated list of glossary entry labels (optionally prefixed with [tag]). Related (possibly dup): [glossaries package reference non-glossary item in see also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191644)

Comment: please se my edit

Comment: `\newacronym` internally uses `\newglossaryentry` so the answer using `\glsadd` can be applied to any type of term regardless of whether it was defined with `\newacronym` or `\newglossaryentry`.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: I have seen your edit, but as I mentioned in my original comment, you can't put commands like `\ref` in the value of the `see` key. The value of that key may only be a list of valid labels. Remove the `see` key from `\newglossaryentry`,  and try defining `\seeref` and use `\glsadd[format=seeref{sec:finfet-transistors}]{finfet}` as per [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191689/19862) in the linked question.

Comment: Using format key results in the see Appendix A apearing *before* the page number

Comment: Move `\glsadd` to the end of the document. If that doesn't work, adjust your MWE to include your modifications.